# Approximating the sum to infinity of derivatives

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

How would one go about approximating the value of

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{d^n\left(J_0(2i\sqrt x)\right)}{dx^n},$$

where $J_0$ is a Bessel function of the first kind, order zero. I expect some numerical approximation would give a result, but maybe there is a more efficient approach to it?

Comment: You can get to an integral expression using the Borel transform. We can formally write:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-t)t^n\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}dt =\int_0^{\infty}f(x+t)\exp(-t)dt$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shall derive an asymptotic formula for large positive $x$. Using the hint in the comments, we obtain
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n J_0 (2{\rm i}\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n I_0 (2\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {I_0 (2\sqrt {x + t} ){\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t} 
$$
for $x>0$. The substitution $t=xs$ yields
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n J_0 (2{\rm i}\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}}  = x\int_0^{ + \infty } {I_0 (2\sqrt{x}\sqrt {1 + s} ){\rm e}^{ - xs} {\rm d}s} .
$$
Now we apply the [asymptotics](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E1)
$$
I_0 (z) = \frac{{{\rm e}^z }}{{\sqrt {2\pi z} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)} \right), \quad z\to+\infty,
$$
to derive
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {I_0 (2\sqrt{x}\sqrt {1 + s} ){\rm e}^{ - xs} {\rm d}s}  =\;& \frac{{x^{3/4} {\rm e}^{2\sqrt x } }}{{2\sqrt \pi  }}\left( \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xs + 2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt {1 + s}  - 1)} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{(1 + s)^{1/4} }}}\right. \\ &+\left. \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{1/2} }}} \right)\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xs + 2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt {1 + s}  - 1)} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{(1 + s)^{3/4} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $x\to+\infty$. By Theorem $2.1$ of Chapter $9$ in F. W. J. Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*, we find
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xs + 2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt {1 + s}  - 1)} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{(1 + s)^{k/4} }}}  = \frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{3/2} }}} \right),\quad k = 1,3
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Therefore
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n J_0 (2{\rm i}\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}}  = \frac{{{\rm e}^{2\sqrt x } }}{{2\sqrt \pi  x^{1/4} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{1/2} }}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Using more terms from the asymptotic expansion of the modified Bessel function and computing a more precise error term in Olver's theorem, the asymptotic result can be improved. Alternatively, we can repeatedly differentiate the asymptotic expansion of the modified Bessel function and formally sum the result. With either of these methods, it is found that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n J_0 (2{\rm i}\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}}  \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^{2\sqrt x } }}{{2\sqrt \pi  x^{1/4} }}\left( 1 + \frac{{17}}{{16x^{1/2} }} + \frac{{425}}{{512x}} + \frac{{347}}{{8192x^{3/2} }}+\ldots\right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.

**Addendum.** If we employ the [power series](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E2)
$$
I_0 (z) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{4}z^2 } \right)^k }}{{k!^2 }}} 
$$
in the integral representation, we obtain, after term-wise integration,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^n J_0 (2{\rm i}\sqrt x )}}{{{\rm d}x^n }}} = {\rm e}^{x}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{Q(k + 1,x)}}{{k!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{e_k (x)}}{{k!}}}=
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = k}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j!}}} } \right)\!\frac{{x^k }}{{k!}}}. 
$$
Here $Q$ is the [normalised incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E4) and $e_k(x)$ is the [$k$th partial sum](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E11) of the exponential power series. This expansion is valid for all complex $x$.

Comment: This is a very elaborate and useful answer. Gary and Saibal, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Follow-up question (hope I am not pushing my luck here). Consider the slightly different case
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}y^n\frac{d^nJ_0(2i\sqrt{yz})}{dyz^n}$$

Would the same procedure still be applicable?

Comment: @DozerD Couldn't you call $yz$ just a single variable, say $w$?

Comment: I was afraid this would be a suggested solution. My question pertains more to the term $y^n$ in front of the derivative. I am not familiar with the Borel transform, how does it affect the transformation?

Comment: @DozerD It will give you $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {I_0 (2\sqrt {x + yt} ){\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}  = x\int_0^{ + \infty } {I_0 (2\sqrt x \sqrt {1 + ys} ){\rm e}^{ - xs} {\rm d}s} .
$$ This is for the case of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {y^n I_0^{(n)} (2\sqrt x )}$.

Comment: Thank you @Gary.